# Opportunity Team email notification - Is Trigger the only way?

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

I have another situation that I need to write a trigger for and I am wondering if there is an out of the box solution I can use.

Basically when a team member is added or deleted from an Opportunity team, I need to send an email notification to that team member and the whole Opportunity team. So far I am not come across any method of doing this without code. Can you please tell me if there is a way to do this without a trigger.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers, triggers all the way I'm afraid...

I think it fails into category of "junction objects" (between User and Opportunity) and [docs say email alerts aren't supported on junction objects](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/workflow_rules_considerations.htm).

Workflows don't work on `OpportunityTeamMember` (the option is both inaccessible from GUI as well as forced creation of OpportunityTeamMember.workflow file fails in Eclipse).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workflow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <alerts>
        <fullName>Team_Modified</fullName>
        <description>Team Modified Notification</description>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <recipients>
            <type>creator</type>
        </recipients>
        <senderType>CurrentUser</senderType>
        <template>unfiled$public/Case_Modified</template>
    </alerts>
    <rules>
        <fullName>Team Modified</fullName>
        <formula>true</formula>
        <actions>
            <name>Team_Modified</name>
            <type>Alert</type>
        </actions>
        <active>true</active>
        <description>Hi StackExchange!</description>
        <triggerType>onCreateOrTriggeringUpdate</triggerType>
    </rules>
</Workflow>
```

renders

```
Save error: OpportunityTeamMember.Team Modified : Cannot create a workflow rule on entity:OpportunityTeamMember
Save error: OpportunityTeamMember.Team_Modified : Cannot create a workflow action on entity:OpportunityTeamMember
```

Same story with AccountContactRole, AccountPartner, OpportunityContactRole etc. - several objects where we can't add fields, customize them (well, except the Role picklist but you get the idea)...

Bonus - [looks like mailing Opp Team members is clunky in general](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpdVAAS) ;)

Comment: Thank you. Kind of expected this but I suppose SF may provide something in upcoming versions.

Comment: Also do you know how I can send am email to all members of an Opportunity team in Apex? I just need to know how I can obtain their emails.

Comment: `SELECT User.Email
FROM OpportunityTeamMember
WHERE OpportunityId = :oppId AND User.isActive = true`. Adapt as you see fit to include an IN clause. Or maybe even subquery would be easiest method of "bulkifying": `SELECT Id, (SELECT User.Email FROM OpportunityTeamMembers WHERE User.IsActive = true)
FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :changedOppsIds` (you'd have to build a set of Opportunity Ids first)

Comment: Thanks. Since I am using this inside a for loop in a trigger, I was hoping to avoid SOQL. Will open a new question with my code. Please do see it.

Comment: Check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4970/799 before actually posting :) should give you hints how to collect all Opp Ids that have to be checked, run only 1 query, then in final loop use the queried data.

Comment: Just created it :) http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5023/trigger-on-opportunityteammember-has-an-error Will check your link now.