# Trigger on OpportunityTeamMember has an error

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

Since there is no out of the box solution to send email notifications to users when they are added/removed from an Opportunity team, I wrote a trigger. So far I have code to handle the addition. This saves without errors but I get the following error when I test the trigger.

```
execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Invalid to address : null: []:
```

This is my trigger:

```
trigger notify_opportunity_team_members on OpportunityTeamMember (after delete, after insert) {

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    for (OpportunityTeamMember o : trigger.new) { 
        String[] toAddresses = new String[]{o.User.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

        mail.setSubject('Addition to an Opportunity Team : ');
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(o.User.FirstName + ' ' + o.User.LastName + ' has been added to the Opportunity Team of: ' + o.Opportunity);
        mail.setHtmlBody(o.User.FirstName + ' ' + o.User.LastName + ' has been added to the Opportunity Team of: <b>' + o.Opportunity);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't we get the user's email using o.User.Email?

Also I need to send this email to all the Opportunity team members, how can I get all their emails? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only "simple fields" are available in the trigger out of the box. In this case it means you can get `UserId` (because that's actual field on the OpportunityTeamMember) but not `User.Name`, `User.Email`, `User.Manager.UserRole.Name` ;)

1. Loop through all Opp Team Members, collect their Ids
2. Run only one query to get info about all users
3. Use that info

The code will be a bit complex so you can save on emails being sent ;)

```
Map<Id, List<Id>> opportunityToUserIdsMap = new Map<Id, List<Id>>(); // stores data similar to "opp 123" => "users John Doe and Jane Smith were added"
Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();

// 1
for(OpportunityTeamMember otm : trigger.new){
    userIds.add(otm.UserId);

    if(!opportunityToUserIdsMap.containsKey(otm.OpportunityId)){
        opportunityToUserIdsMap.put(otm.OpportunityId, new List<Id>{otm.UserId});
    } else {
        opportunityToUserIdsMap.get(otm.OpportunityId).add(otm.UserId);
    }
}

// 2 - only 1 query for users. And only one for Opportunities (unless you don't want to display their names in email?)
Map<Id, User> affectedUsers = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :userIds]);
Map<Id, Opportunity> affectedOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityToUserIdsMap.keyset()]);

// 3
for(Id oppId : opportunityToUserIdsMap.keyset()){
    // we have Opportunity Id, we can use it to retrieve more data about it
    Opportunity o = affectedOpps.get(oppId);
    List<String> emails = new List<String>();

    // and we can use it to get list of user ids which can then be used to match to emails
    for(Id userId : opportunityToUserIdsMap.get(oppId)){
        User u = affectedUsers.get(userId);
        emails.add(u.Email);
    }

    System.debug('Email about changes to Team under ' + o.Name + ' should be sent to: ' + emails);
    // generate emails here but only keep adding them to the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]
}
// and perform the email sending call (might have multiple emails in it) outside of the loop ;)
```